# Programmatically check if a COM port exists in C#

Tags: c#, exception, serial-port

I just got myself into using the SerialPort object in C# and I realised it throws an exception saying that "COM1" does not exist.
I checked my device manager to see what COM ports I can use, but is there a way to find out what COM ports are available and programmatically select one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use [`SerialPort.GetPortNames()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns an array of strings of available port names.

Then create your `SerialPort` object by specifying one of the names in the constructor.

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
SerialPort port = new SerialPort(ports[0]);  // create using first existing serial port, for example
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.
In my problem I created a method called USBValidator, it has a 'for' loop with i starting at 0 and ending at SerialPort.GetPortNames().Length. Inside that loop I put USB.PortName = SerialPort.GetPortNames()[i], which automatically made my serial port be assigned to the right COM port.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner :

```
if(SerialPort.GetPortNames().ToList().Contains(comportName)) 
{
    port = new SerialPort(comportName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
string portExists = SerialPort.GetPortNames().Any(x => x == "COM1");
```

Comment: I prefer this inline solution.